# Convert different languages date string to Datetime format

Tags: php, datetime

I try to convert this string : `Août 2016` to `datetime` format in PHP.
It perfectly works with an english format (August 2016) using `createFromFormat('M Y', $string)` but doesn't work with a different language.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: your question not clear, can you specify the language which is you tried?

Comment: In my case, it is French (Août 2016)

Answer (score 0):

Look at: http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.parse.php
But you have to know the language that is used.